# При большой нагрузке получаю SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on

Tags: php, mysql

Запуcтили сайт, всё вроде бы хорошо, но начала вылетать ошибка что не может подключиться
заметил что это происходит при большой нагрузке.
с другого сервера ещё подключается другая аппликация для синхронизации

my.cnf

```
-bash-4.2$ more my.cnf
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
innodb_open_files=20000
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 32M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
bind-address = <IP>
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
open-files-limit=16384
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Comment: приложите пожалуйста **my.cnf** к вашему вопросу

Comment: добавил в описание проблемы